# What wasp like insect breeds in clay pots with dead spiders?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, reproduction, wasps

I found several small clay pots of oval/cigar shape roughly 2cm long in a rarely used window in the house, because a wasp like insect was flying into a small cavity of the window.

I removed one and found dead spiders inside.

[image: clay pot and spiders]

I let the rest of the nest alone and closed the window again. I guess I don't have to bother them if they aren't bothering me.

**I'm wondering what type of insect is that building such nests?** It looked like a cross between a wasp and a hornet.
As far as I know, wasps and hornets build their nests from wood, which gives them a paper like material. This one however is made from soil/dirt.

I'm also not sure if spiders are the only food. But given the street lamps outside, I suspect that spiders are very available and easy to catch.

The region is central Europe.

Comment: You might be interested in the answer to my question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/62724/which-organism-built-this-2-cm-long-sandy-tube

Comment: They are mud daubers. Rarely sting humans and hunt spiders. Seem like a pretty helpful hornet to me!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's some sort of potter wasp/mason wasp (Eumeninae). The spiders are paralyzed and brought there as food for its larvae.
Here is an example of an opened nest I found on [Bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net/node/view/800551) that looks similar to yours:

[image]

I don't know if it's possible to say what species it is from the nest.

Comment: Please note another family does similar things: the [Sceliphron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sceliphron) which is also common in Europe (some species are also invasive). After by the pictures and the victimology, I cannot say which type of family/genus/species.

Comment: Oh i didn't know their nests were so similar! Since the author of the question saw the animals, and described them as "like a cross between a wasp and a hornet" they should be able to tell of it was a potter wasp or Sceliphron since the latter is much more slender.