# Were these spiders burried alive by a spider wasp?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, reproduction, wasps

I moved a stone plate in the garden in europe, that was stored vertically, leaning against another one.
In the space between the two, I found some soil with small cavities filled with spiders.

[image: spiders in cavities]

Most of the spiders had a (what I think is a) larva attached to their backside. See the white sausage thing in the right half of the image. I noticed that there's what seems to be spider web on the right edge of the cavity.
[image: spider with larva in cavity]

Some of the spiders showed movement when lightly blowing air onto them. I took some of them out to get more detailed photos. The larva seems to have a white/translucent head attached to the spider body. The internals of the larva appear to be light brown through the translucent body. The larva has a thin white line at the sides of its body.

[image: spider with larva]
[image: spider with larva]

The least lively of the spiders had a larger larva attached. It has a darker inside and some white dots on its body. It disengaged from its spider and the mouth is visible.
[image: spider with bigger larva]
[image: spider with bigger larva]

A while ago, [I found other spiders in a comparable situation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/49088/17634). Having learned that some wasps apparently catch spiders and paralyze them, to be eaten by their larvae, I did some search and found [spider wasps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_wasp)

Is the above the work of a spider wasp? I had a look at [bugguide - Family Pompilidae - Spider Wasps](https://bugguide.net/node/view/3919), but there are no images of their burrows shown.

Comment: That's horrific.

Comment: Excellent photos. Also look up mud dauber wasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, I'd say it is the work of a spider wasp. I'm not familiar with those, so I can't determine what species or genus it might be. But it sure does look similar to [some of those stages of the larvae](https://jhr.pensoft.net/article/5833/zoom/fig/11/). Very nice pictures! I will try to find out what the white dots on the body of the oldest larva (the last and hungry one) are.

Comment: In picture (G) of your link one can see those white dots as well - would be interesting what those are all about - please keep us updated if you find out more.